# Ubuntu 14.04: No sound output! (Well, mostly no sound)

Tags: 14.04, sound

I am totally new to Ubuntu so please forgive my ignorance :) I was trying to read the previous posted questions but none seem to be the same as what I have right now. (Please point me in the right direction if I missed it)

I installed a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows7 on my laptop and now there is no sound output when I am in Ubuntu...

Well, mostly no sound because after tinkering with the alsa mixer I managed to make the clicking sound come out when I click the mute/unmute option in the sound settings. Other than that clicking sound there is totally no sound. Please help.

I just wanted to add the details from the terminal about the output, I have no idea if this information would be helpful.

`lspci -nnk | grep -ia2 audio` output:

```
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Server Board S1200BTS / Apple MacBook Pro 8,1/8,2 [8086:7270]
  Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
  Subsystem: Intel CorporationApple MacbookPro7,2 [Core i7, 15", 2011] [8086:7270]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 and System76 notebook.

Behold solution:

```
sudo su
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

[Source](http://totoshko88.livejournal.com/61645.html) (**not in English**)
Find more info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)